# Code using std::iter::IntoIterator does not work

Tags: rust, iterator

Why the following Rust code does not compile?

```rust
let yy: dyn std::iter::IntoIterator<Item = i32, IntoIter = std::vec::IntoIter<i32>> =
    std::vec::Vec::new();
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:30:9
   |
29 |     let yy: dyn std::iter::IntoIterator<Item = i32, IntoIter = std::vec::IntoIter<i32>> =
   |             --------------------------------------------------------------------------- expected due to this
30 |         std::vec::Vec::new();
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn std::iter::IntoIterator`, found struct `std::vec::Vec`
   |
   = note: expected trait object `dyn std::iter::IntoIterator<IntoIter = std::vec::IntoIter<i32>, Item = i32>`
                    found struct `std::vec::Vec<_>`
```

Accordingly my understanding, this should compile because [there is](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html):

```rust
impl<T> IntoIterator for Vec<T>
```

Comment: In order to make a trait object, you would need to use `Box` like in these [examples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html).

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of [this page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.IntoIter.html) you can read:

> This struct is created by the into_iter method on Vec

I don't know exactly what you want but this could be accepted by the compiler.

```rust
    let yy: &dyn std::iter::IntoIterator<
        Item = i32,
        IntoIter = std::vec::IntoIter<i32>,
    > = &std::vec::Vec::new().into_iter();
```